# how to find the duration between two dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to find the duration between the two date columns. For this i used the DATEDIFF function to find number years and months separately but wanted both results in single column.
The two columns are given below.

```
start_dt      |    end_dt
06-Oct-2009      15-Jul-2011
```

Result which needed

```
Duration(years.months)
2.3
```

Comment: Can't you use months as the datepart argument and divide by 12?

Comment: I found your post confusing. What exactly did you type? What did you get?
I suppose the link below can help you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there is no out-of-the-box API to provide the result in the format you mentioned. You need to use the `DATEDIFF` function to get the difference in the least denomination you need and then divide the result with appropriate value to get the duration in the format required. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME
DECLARE @end DATETIME
DECLARE @duration INT

SELECT @start = '2009-10-06', @end = '2011-07-15'
SELECT @duration = DATEDIFF(mm, @start, @end)
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @duration / 12) + '.' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @duration % 12)
```

This can be better achieved by writing a function that would take the dates and least denomination and returns the duration in the format needed, as it would require TSQL and plain SQL wouldn't suffice.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF( mm, start_dt, end_dt) / 12 AS years
    , DATEDIFF( mm, start_dt, end_dt) % 12 AS months
```

Answer (score 1):

**QUERY :**

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()), 103) AS FinalDay,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, HRM_EmpGenDtls.DOJ, 106) AS DOJ,
    CONVERT(varchar, DATEDIFF(year, HRM_EmpGenDtls.DOJ, GETDATE())) + ' Years' + ' ' +                      
    CONVERT(varchar, DATEDIFF(month, HRM_EmpGenDtls.DOJ, GETDATE()) - (datediff(year, HRM_EmpGenDtls.DOJ, GETDATE()) * 12)) + ' Months' + ' ' +      CONVERT(varchar, datepart(d,GETDATE()) - datepart(d, HRM_EmpGenDtls.DOJ)) + ' Days' AS ServicePeriod   
FROM HRM_EmpGenDtls
```

That gives following answer :

```
FinalDay    DOJ ServicePeriod

10/10/2013  03 Sep 2012 1 Years 0 Months 7 Days
10/10/2013  01 Jan 2000 13 Years 8 Months 9 Days
10/10/2013  22 Aug 2000 13 Years 1 Months -12 Days
10/10/2013  22 Aug 2000 13 Years 1 Months -12 Days
10/10/2013  22 Aug 2000 13 Years 1 Months -12 Days
10/10/2013  22 Aug 2000 13 Years 1 Months -12 Days
10/10/2013  22 Aug 2000 13 Years 1 Months -12 Days
10/10/2013  04 Sep 2012 1 Years 0 Months 6 Days
```

Comment: This query will helpful to find difference between two dates in Years, Months and days

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(month, start_dt, end_dt) / 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It might help

```
select cast (DATEDIFF(m,'06-Oct-2009','15-Jul-2011')/12 as varchar(25)) + '.' + cast (DATEDIFF(m,'06-Oct-2009','15-Jul-2011')%12 as varchar(25))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried by this-

```
    SELECT
      CONVERT(varchar,DATEDIFF(MONTH,SAKUSEITIME,KOSHINTIME)/12)+'.'
      +CONVERT(varchar,DATEDIFF(MONTH,SAKUSEITIME,KOSHINTIME)%12) Duration
    FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my function for finding the difference in time between two dates.

```
ALTER FUNCTION functionName
-- The first imput is the start time and the second input is the end time.
@StartTime datetime, @EndTime datetime

RETURNS varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Duration varchar(15)


SET @Duration =
convert(nvarchar(10),(COALESCE (DATEDIFF(day,@StartTime,@EndTime),DATEDIFF(day,@StartTime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))) + '.' +
right('00'+ISNULL(convert(nvarchar(10),(COALESCE (DATEDIFF(hour,@StartTime,@EndTime)%24,DATEDIFF(hour,@StartTime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)%24))),' '),2) + ':' +
right('00'+ISNULL(convert(nvarchar(10),(COALESCE (DATEDIFF(minute,@StartTime,@EndTime)%60,DATEDIFF(minute,@StartTime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)%60))),' '),2) + ':' +
right('00'+ISNULL(convert(nvarchar(10),(COALESCE (DATEDIFF(second,@StartTime,@EndTime)%60,DATEDIFF(second,@StartTime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)%60))),' '),2)
    -- Calculates the difference in each until of time, finds the remainder, and add the pieces of the timestamp together.
    RETURN @Duration

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime
select @StartDate = '2016-08-24 14:44:54.513',@EndDate='2016-08-24 14:48:16.173'
Select convert(varchar,CAST((@EndDate-@StartDate) as time(0))) '[hh:mm:ss]'
```

Comment: Calculate Duration between from and to datetime datatype in Sql server, it will throw only hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".