# Duration Between Two Dates in sql

Tags: sql

How to get Duration Between Two Dates in sql

Here is the code I tried using sql:

```
select A.Product_name,
   B.DeliveredDate,
   DATEDIFF (m,'01/12/2012',B.DeliveredDate)as 'date' 
From Support_RMA A INNER JOIN UnInvoicedProducts B 
   ON  A.Product_name = B.ProductName 
Where A.Customer_name='Mr. Kamalesh Gupta'
```

Here i am getting date=12 but i need date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

Comment: How can a difference between two dates ever be a date?

Comment: You will get a timespan, dd/MM/yyyy is not a format in with you can present a duration.

Comment: Riddle me this... you have two dates: 23/05/13 and 26/06/13. What should the result be?

Comment: "I am getting date=12 but I need date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format." - OK, so what is the actual answer you would like to see?

Comment: the result will be either in months i.e. 12 months or year that is 1 not like a date i.e. dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775480/how-to-find-the-duration-between-two-dates

Answer (score -2):

select DATEDIFF(mm,getdate(),getdate())

Comment: Your query returns `0` and is not solving the Asker's question